# Node in a coordinate system with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a `TikZ` command which creates a coordinate system. So far, I have created this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrartcl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\coordinatesystem}[4]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=1, gray!40] (#1,#2) grid (#3,#4);
        \draw[-stealth,very thick] (#1,0) -- (#3,0);
        \draw[-stealth,very thick] (0,#2) -- (0,#4);
        \foreach \x in {#1,...,#3}
        \foreach \y in {#2,...,#4}
        {
            \node[text=gray!30, below] at (\x,0) {$\x$};
            \node[text=gray!30, left] at (0,\y) {$\y$};     
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\coordinatesystem{-5}{-5}{3}{4}

\end{document}
```

I would like the x-axis nodes to be slightly further to the right to avoid a collision with the coordinate system lines. Similarly, I would like the y-axis nodes to be slightly higher than they are now. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at `xshift` and `yshift`.

Comment: I tried to implement it that way, but somehow I failed, what do you suggest exactly?

Comment: `\node[text=gray!30, below, yshift=2pt] at (\x,0) {$\x$};` and `\node[text=gray!30, left, xshift=-2pt] at (0,\y) {$\y$};` except for zeros. You could also try to play with `pgfplots`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked just fine! (I forgot pt before ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You dont want to print zeros on the x-y scales modify your code like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\coordinatesystem}[4]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=1, gray!40] (#1,#2) grid (#3,#4);
        \draw[-stealth,very thick] (#1,0) -- (#3,0);
        \draw[-stealth,very thick] (0,#2) -- (0,#4);
        \foreach \x in {#1,...,#3}
        \foreach \y in {#2,...,#4}
        {
            \ifnum \x=0 
            \relax%
            \else %
            {\node[text=gray!30, below] at (\x,0)  {$\x$};}
            \fi
            
            \ifnum \y=0 
            \relax%
            \else %
            {\node[text=gray!30, left] at (0,\y) {$\y$};}
            \fi     
        }
        \node[text=gray!30] at (-.3,-.3) {$O$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \coordinatesystem{-5}{-5}{3}{4}\,
    \coordinatesystem{-4}{-5}{4}{4}
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**ADD**: In any case a coordinate system alone is useless. With the above answer you cant put any graph or plot. So You need to have the `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` outside the \newcommand definition and have, for example, something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\coordinatesystem}[4]{
        \draw[step=1, gray!40] (#1,#2) grid (#3,#4);
        \draw[-stealth,very thick] (#1,0) -- (#3,0);
        \draw[-stealth,very thick] (0,#2) -- (0,#4);
        \foreach \x in {#1,...,#3}
        \foreach \y in {#2,...,#4}
        {
            \ifnum \x=0 
            \relax%
            \else %
            {\node[text=gray!30, below] at (\x,0)  {$\x$};}
            \fi
            
            \ifnum \y=0 
            \relax%
            \else %
            {\node[text=gray!30, left] at (0,\y) {$\y$};}
            \fi     
        }
        \node[text=gray!30] at (-.3,-.3) {$O$}; 
        }

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinatesystem{-4}{-5}{4}{4}
    \clip (-4,-5) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw[cyan,line width=2pt] plot[domain=-4:4] (\x,-\x-1);
    \draw[magenta,line width=2pt] plot[domain=-4:4,smooth] (\x,\x*\x-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the above code You have this output:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks, that looks really nice!